# How to use session method load() in the hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, session

When I use the load method in the session of abnormalities
`java.lang.ClassCastException: www.csdn.net.blank.bean.City_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy`

From api:

> You should not use this method to determine if an instance exists (use
>   get() instead). Use this only to retrieve an instance that you assume
>   exists, where non-existence would be an actual error.

This version is not the load method for persistent objects?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good explanation:
http://way2java.com/hibernate/difference-bewteen-session-get-and-session-load-in-hibernate/

load() is called lazy fetching and returns a Proxy of the persistence object not the actual persistence object (see above article for explanation.)

get() is called eager fetching and returns the actual persistence object. This method should also be used if you are unsure if the instance actually exists.

At least this is how I understand it from reading the article above.

It sounds like you want to be using get().

From http://way2java.com/hibernate/difference-bewteen-session-get-and-session-load-in-hibernate/:

[image: Session Get vs Session Load comparison]

Comment: "5.  get() always hits the db" 
No! it doesn't. See the output in this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571072/why-session-get-in-hibernate-doesnt-always-hit-the-database